# Using multiple --properties arguments via JBoss CLI

Tags: jboss, wildfly-10

I would like to know, if is possible to run following command (or something like this) with more than one properties file in --properties argument.

```
$JBOSS_HOME/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect --user=admin --password=admin --properties=init.properties --properties=jvm.properties --file=init.cli
```

or

```
$JBOSS_HOME/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect --user=admin --password=admin --properties=init.properties jvm.properties --file=init.cli
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can! You were actually right in your first given example.

---

Here's a non-practical illustration:

#### hello.properties

```
hello=Hello from the
```

#### world.properties

```
world='Second' property file
```

#### echo.cli

```
set hello=${hello}
set world=${world}
echo $hello $world
```

Running:

```
$ $JBOSS_HOME/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect --properties=hello.properties --properties=world.properties --file=echo.cli
Hello from the 'Second' property file
```